# iconv_get_encoding not available in some hosts

Tags: php

I'm using [iconv_get_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-get-encoding.php) but some hosting compile PHP without the iconv extension (that is enable by default).

Which substitution for this function do you recommend?

This function is used by a system with a [Zend Framework class to validate hostnames](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.hostname)

This is the part of the code where is used:
(...)

```
        // Check input against DNS hostname schema
        if ((count($domainParts) > 1) && (strlen($value) >= 4) && (strlen($value) <= 254)) {
            $status = false;

            $origenc = iconv_get_encoding('internal_encoding');
            iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
            do {
                // First check TLD
                $matches = array();
                if (preg_match('/([^.]{2,10})$/i', end($domainParts), $matches) ||
                    (end($domainParts) == 'ایران') || (end($domainParts) == '中国') ||
                    (end($domainParts) == '公司') || (end($domainParts) == '网络')) {
```

(...)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, since the iconv extension is not available its hard to tell a workaroung without knowing what's your goal.